# perform action on enter pressed in div using jquery

Tags: jquery

There are some similar thread, I already have checked and tested. But dont work for my case.

I have comment box where I want to post comment when user press `Enter` key.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="commentMark" id="commentMark-<?php  echo $row['p_id'];?>" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Write a comment'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Write a comment') this.value = ''" onKeyPress="return SubmitComment(this,event)" wrap="hard" name="commentMark" style=" background-color:#fff; overflow: hidden;">Write a comment</div>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
 $('.commentMark').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
 });
});

// $("$commentMark").keypress(function (e) ..
```

also doe not performs any action.

What's wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I also checked on fiddle that it work. But dont know what wrong on my localhost.
It looks like.

wall.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('.commentMark').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
 });
});
</script>
<?php
<div contenteditable="true" class="commentMark" id="commentMark-<?php  echo $row['p_id'];?>" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Write a comment'" onfocus="if (this.value=='Write a comment') this.value = ''" onKeyPress="return SubmitComment(this,event)" wrap="hard" name="commentMark" style=" background-color:#fff; overflow: hidden;">Write a comment</div>
?>
```

Anything wrong now? because still it does not work on my localhost.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, your code works perfectly.  possible you might missed to add jQuery lib.

Comment: Do you get to see the `div` in the page? I am not much familiar with PHP but don't you need a `echo`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly, there is just an issue, are you sure in your code you're using

```
$('.commentMark').keypress(function (e) {
```

because I can see another line of code too

```
// $("$commentMark").keypress(function (e) ..
```

Even its commented, but make sure its not being used. Because `$` isn't used in selectors! `.` or `#` is used similar to CSS.

**Edit**

Use this:

```
<div onkeydown="alrtme()"></div>
```

Hey, write all the other properties as they have to, but just update the onkeydown in the div.

Then update the function as

```
function alrtme(){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
  }
});
```

This is a simple one, which would run when there is a `keydown` event on the div. And would run and if the key is enter then the alert would come up!

**Edit for a bug in your fiddle:**

I was going to edit the fiddle, then I thought I should find a `return` and guess what did I find,

```
function SubmitComment(myfield,e) {
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
else return true;
if (keycode == 13)
{

}
else
return true;
}
```

its the last one, the `SubmitComment` is the function that would when the key is pressed. And there you have set the enterkey return to nothing or false. Change it there and write it as:

```
function SubmitComment(myfield){
  if (event.keyCode == 13){
      /* 
       * you don't need to use the keycode variable, just use them as this..
       * and then submit it ..
       */ 
  }
else
return true;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: IT works on fiddle but due to some reason not on my localsystem. Actually this file wall.php is included in index.php. 
see if you can : https://github.com/karimkhanp/commentbox_quora/blob/master/yepinol/Wall/wall.php   line: 433. In that textarea I have replace by div and now I am facing above issue.

Comment: Then make sure you're selecting the same thing (div) that way you'll get it. Because your code is perfect :) Don't worry, just try to select it.

Comment: @Afazaal: jazakallah. I have selected same div, but no luck!

Comment: @Programming_crazy, have a look now :)

Comment: interesting thing is if I take keycode for a-z or A-Z and check it, it validates condition and perform alert. But for enter it does not!

Comment: that should not happen here, are you blocking enter or are you using `return false` somewhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39119/discussion-between-programming-crazy-and-afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan)

Comment: there was a bug in your code, i have updated the function! Please run it..:)

Comment: same link does not show any change :(. If you udpated then it may have changed url

Comment: No there is no change, i have not updated that. I have sent the update here in my answer.

Comment: I could not undestant what change I should made!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you've included the `jQuery` library. I've checked the code and its working. You can view it here.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikashh/2mwRF/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Vijash: IT works on fiddle but due to some reason not on my localsystem. Actually this file wall.php is included in index.php. 
see if you can : https://github.com/karimkhanp/commentbox_quora/blob/master/yepinol/Wall/wall.php   line: 433. In that textarea I have replace by div and now I am facing above issue.

Comment: I've read the comment that you've specified above. I think, their is also another event binded on the enter event. Please add another div inside the form with different name and class and perform the same action for debuggin.